# How do I change com.day.cq.rewriter.xml.XSLTTransformer

Tags: java, aem

I have found several references on web pages such as this one: http://www.cqblueprints.com/tipsandtricks/pdfrendering.html and this one: http://cq-concepts.blogspot.com/ that say to modify com.day.cq.rewriter.xml.XSLTTransformer.

The problem is, how do I do that? I've googled, but can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by modify or change "com.day.cq.rewriter.xml.XSLTTransformer" ??

Comment: @RC The documents I pasted links to say that I need to change that class. That is all I know.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MohitBansal Rendering PDFs based on template type.

Comment: I tried this once myself and gave up on it. The only thing you can modify is the XSTL file itself: /libs/wcm/core/content/pdf/page2fo.xsl